# GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN always returns 0

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

I'm trying to use the transform feedback functionality of OpenGL. I've written a minimalistic vertex shader and created a program with it (there's no fragment shader). I've also made a call to `glTransformFeedbackVaryings` with a single output varying name and I've set the buffer mode to be `GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS`. The shader program compiles and links fine (I also make sure I link after the `glTransformFeedbackVaryings` call.

I've enabled a single vertex attrib array using `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, allocated a VBO for the generic vertex attributes and made a call to `glVertexAttribPointer` for the attribute.

I've bound the `TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` to another buffer which I've generated and created a data store which should be plenty big enough to be written to during transform feedback.

I then enable transform feedback and call `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1000)`. I don't get any crashes throughout the running of the program.

The problem is that I'm getting no indication that the transform feedback is writing anything to the `TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` during the `glDrawArrays` call. I set up a query which monitors  `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN` and this always returns 0. No matter what I try I can't seem to get the transform feedback to write ANYTHING (never mind anything meaningful!)

If anyone has any suggestions as to how I could get the transform feedback to write anything, or things that I should check for please let me know!

*Note: I can't use transform feedback objects and I'm not using vertex array objects.*

Comment: Your algorithm seems fine; you probably have a bug in your code. There's no way to tell without actually seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wrote a simple .cpp file that used transform feedback in as few lines of code as possible and then following the steps back in my proper application pointed out a problem in how I was using `glBindBufferBase` (whilst also trying some other things). The query is returning the expected value now so I think I'm back on track! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem ended up being how I was calling `glBindBufferBase`. Given that I can't see this function call in the original question it may have been that I omitted it altogether.

Certainly I didn't realise that the `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` also has to be bound with a call to `glBindBuffer` to the correct buffer object before `calling glBindBufferBase`.